# Bootstrap Header Logo Image Not Showing in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

Bare in mind I'm fairly novice with HTML and CSS. I've got a logo in my bootstrap header on my website ([www.prettyugly.co.nz](http://www.prettyugly.co.nz))

I originally used the follow code to display it and it worked fine in Chrome

```
.image {
  content: url("/img/logo-white.png");
}
```

then this in the HTML to call that CSS

```
<div class="image"></div>
```

I since learned that you have to use the :before command for content to work in Firefox, however I can't get it to work across the board.

Any ideas?

Comment: Replace `content` with `background` or `background-image`.

Comment: Do you also have to specify a dimension for that or will it just display at 100% of the image dimension?

Comment: You have a lot of possibilities, learn more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-image.asp) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/background-image).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it still doesn't display an image. Both `background: url("/img/logo-white.png");` and `background-image: url("/img/logo-white.png");` don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply show the image using (HTML):

```
<div><img src="/img/logo-white.png" /></div>
```

But if you want to set it as `background`, then you should use (CSS):

```
.image {
    background-image: url("/img/logo-white.png");
    width: 225px; height: 63px; /* Dimensions of image */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I just tried that and it displays on Chrome but not Firefox.

See this link for a screengrab - http://iforce.co.nz/i/c2utjpbe.hju.jpg

Comment: I'm using Firefox and I can see the image. You need to set `width: 225px; height: 63px;` also.

Comment: Oh its working now! Thank you :) Is there a way I can put alt tags in the CSS for SEO?

Comment: It's not necessary, only when you are using `img` tag in HTML :) You can [read this article](http://christianheilmann.com/2009/02/25/so-how-do-you-add-alternative-text-to-background-images/) about that.